# QMimeData encoding types

Tags: qt

In my app I'm doing internal drag and drops with a QTreeView.  Using the tutorial I can happily drag and drop a single leaf by encoding it into a string list using the mime type "application/vnd.text.list".

I then wanted to drag and drop a tree node that had some children and thought the best route to doing this would be to encode the pointer to the node and iterate through all the children in the dropMimeData method.

I declared a mime type in the mimeTypes() method:

```
QStringList toResultModel::mimeTypes() const {
    QStringList types;
    types << "text/plain";
    types << "application/vnd.mypointerlist.list";
    return types;
}
```

And tried to pass the same string list across, but the application crashes in the dropMimeData() method.

It seems the mime type "application/vnd.text.list" has some hidden meaning which I am unable to find.

I have found this source code:  http://fossies.org/linux/tora/src/toresultmodel.cpp where the author sets up a custom coding type "application/vnd.tomodel.list" and also uses "application/vnd.int.list".

What are the rules in using encoding types? 
Where are the built-in types strings defined? 
Which type should I use for passing a pointer to a tree node?

Answer (score 5):

Four years later...

From the information you give, if your method crashes, it's not related to Drag and Drop in particular, there is some error you need to find in the code. that said, let me clarify D&D in Qt, and answer your question about MIME types. While you have indeed solved the problem you had four years ago, this may be useful for other users today.

---

You may define your own type for the purpose of your application or reuse an existing one. How to choose?

**Can you use an existing MIME type, like text/plain?**

- Think about your application being the target of a D&D operation initiated from another application. Can you accept an existing MIME type and retrieve your data from it?
- Think about another application being the target of a D&D operation initiated from within your application. Could this application handle an existing MIME type?

If this answer is no to any of the questions, then you might have to use your own specific MIME type.

**The format name itself is not important**

The constraint is that it must be unique, so that you can't receive incorrectly formatted MIME data from another application, and other applications can identify the MIME type as one they cannot handle, and ignore it.

The exact MIME type name doesn't matter as you'll provide the encoder and the decoder into your data model (e.g. see [this introduction to view/model for Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#encoding-exported-data)), as well as other information about the MIME type(s) used.

1. In `QAbstractItemModel::mimeTypes`, list only the MIME types you are able to deal with. If you don't plan to accept or send MIME data from/to other applications, there is no need to allow more than your specific MIME type.
2. When your application is the source of a D&D operation, encode (serialize) the MIME data in `QAbstractItemModel::mimeData(indexes)`. The result of the serialization must be a byte array, even when there are multiple indexes to be dragged. The internal format is yours. Include any information required to decode (de-serialize) MIME data. Note that you must provide encoded data in each of the MIME type you've listed in `QAbstractItemModel::mimeTypes` (see previous point).
3. When your D&D data are dragged over your application UI, `QAbstractItemModel::canDropMimeData(self, mime_data, action, row, column, parent)` is called to determine if this location is valid for a drop. You may determine here whether the drop should be allowed at this location. In particular, you may test the content of the MIME data provided, and use `mime_data.hasFormat(mime_type)` to check if the format you expect is found in the data about to be drooped. Returning `false` will prevent a drop at this location and a "not allowed here" indication will be provided to the user (this won't cancel the D&D operation itself, the user can continue to move the mouse elsewhere).
4. When the data is actually dropped, `QAbstractItemModel::dropMimeData(mime_data, action, row, column, parent)` is called. Get the MIME data format(s) used using `QMimeData::hasFormat(mime_type)`. If you don't find the MIME type you expect, ignore the drop operation as you cannot decode the data provided (the D&D was initiated from another application). This shouldn't happen as prior to drop data, the application has called `QAbstractItemModel::canDropMimeData` as seen in the previous point. If everything is ok decode the MIME data, and update your model with the data received.

On the other hand, your tree leaf data may fit as path+name encoded in `text/plain` MIME data, so maybe you can just use this type too. However as other applications can generate `text/plain` data that don't contain a tree leaf description, you need, in this case, to have a mean to identify irrelevant data and ignore them. It's obvious such approach will need more code for verification of the validity of the drop action than when using a specific MIME type. However this allows to interact with other applications, and is indeed relevant to drag from well know applications like Excel (e.g. cell content) or Firefox (e.g. rich text or image), else we couldn't re-use information from these applications using D&D.

**Do you need to use `vnd` prefix?**

`vnd` in the MIME type means "vendor specific". This prefix is used to distinguish vendors created MIME types from those created by IANA authority. From [RFC 6838](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6838):

> Vendor-tree registrations will be distinguished by the leading facet
> "vnd.". That may be followed, at the discretion of the registrant, by
> either a media subtype name from a well-known producer (e.g.,
> "vnd.mudpie") or by an IANA-approved designation of the producer's
> name that is followed by a media type or product designation (e.g.,
> vnd.bigcompany.funnypictures).

So in your Drag&Drop tutorial the `application/vnd.text.list` is a specific one supposedly created by some vendor for their own purpose. Same for `application/vnd.mypointerlist.list`

In contrast, `text/plain` is a standard MIME type defined by IANA in [RFC 2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046). This defines a human readable text:

> Plain text does not provide for or allow    formatting commands, font
> attribute specifications, processing    instructions, interpretation
> directives, or content markup.  Plain    text is seen simply as a
> linear sequence of characters, possibly    interrupted by line breaks
> or page breaks.  Plain text may allow the    stacking of several
> characters in the same position in the text.    Plain text in scripts
> like Arabic and Hebrew may also include    facilitites that allow the
> arbitrary mixing of text segments with    opposite writing directions.

For your type, you may want to use `vnd` followed by a subtype which is specific to your application, for consistency considerations. But as seen, the actual name is not important, as long as you know which one you use and you are not interacting with other applications in the D&D chain.

Comment: "When your D&D data are dragged over your application UI, `QAbstractItemModel::canDropMimeData(self, mime_data, action, row, column, parent)` is called to determine if this location is valid for a drop." - That doesn't always seem to be case. I can't verify this in my application, and in [Using Drag and Drop with Item Views](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#using-drag-and-drop-with-item-views), `canDropMimeData` is explicitly called from `dropMimeData`. Am I missing something?

Comment: My understanding is the D&D infrastructure calls `canDropMimeData` periodically during the drag to show the "drop allowed/forbidden" pointer and allow drop to occur. `canDropMimeData` is called again at the closest of the data change to ensure the condition is still true (the last check done while dragging maybe outdated, e.g. if the UI thread is busy, the refresh is slow and the item below the mouse has been already moved). I don't see another case where calling `canDropMimeData` during the drag and during the drop would return different values, but I must say I havent' used Qt since a while.

Comment: @mkl, What you might be missing is that QAbstractItemModel::canDropMimeData() is called (indirectly) from QAbstractItemView::dragMoveEvent(). If you override dragMoveEvent(), you need to call the base class version in your override. I agree that the documentation to which you refer is not clear on this point. mins is also correct that checking one last time in dropMimeData() is correct.

Comment: Also, if you call QAbstractItemModel::canDropMimeData() from your override, then it will call your supportedDropActions() and mimeTypes(), since you override these. That means that you don't have to check those yourself. E.g.:  
  
`    if (!QAbstractItemModel::canDropMimeData(data, action, row, column, parent))   
        return false;`